# Swift start uitableviewcell below transparent sticky header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to show the first cell in a `UITableView` section exactly below  a **transparent header?**

Current attempt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 75
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReminderHeaderTableViewCell") as! ReminderHeaderTableViewCell
    cell.contentView.tag = section

    return cell.contentView
}
```

Result:
[Header and then cell at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gryu.png)

Expectation:
[Header and then cell exactly at below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcOg6.png)

Comment: can you provide some more insight, perhaps a screenshot of what the problem is ?

Comment: @DarkInnocence Right now I use UITableViewStyle.Plain and sticky header is work well. What I consist is the first cell always start at bottom of header. Because header is transparent, I want to the first cell start exactly at bellow of transparent header.

Comment: Is your goal having no header for the first section?

Comment: @Larme No, I already update question with image

Comment: @DarkInnocence Ialready update question with image